# facebook->getUser return null with nginx

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I'm use nginx as a Reverse Proxy:

```
location /facebook/
{

    proxy_pass  http://upload  #this is an nother server;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

and my code:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId'  => "xx", 
 'secret' => "xxxxxxxx", 
));


$user = $facebook->getUser();


if ($user){
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    var_dump($user_profile);
}

else
{

    $url=$facebook->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope' => $req_perms) );
    //if I used nginx I must change redirect_uri 
    $url = str_replace('http%3A%2F%2Fupload%2F', 'http%3A%2F%2F'. $mydomian .'%2F',$url);
    header("Location:".$url);
}
```

If I do not use nginx as Reverse Proxy,it works fine, but if I use it, it creates an endless loop because `$facebook->getUser()` returns 0. I have no idea what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The URL that you are logging in on must match the one that is set in the developer app https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOUR_APP_ID/summary under '*Select how your app integrates with Facebook'* otherwise it won't work.

Comment: I used the same domain name to test, the difference is only one used nginx as proxy,and I used $url = str_replace('http%3A%2F%2Fupload%2F', 'http%3A%2F%2F'. $mydomian .'%2F',$url),so I think their callback url are the same, and I think app seeting is not the reason, Thank you anyway